# Sending application requests that appear in the left column on Facebook home page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

At the left column on facebook's home page, a notification from Facebook applications appears with a gray character, for example, "APPLICATION NAME [1]".

For example, Badoo app displays this type of notification when a friend has answered my question.

How do I display this notification for my own application?

Answer (score 3):

Your English is great, hkweb. To send the user a "Notification", you must send a POST request to the user's [/apprequests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/apprequest/) connection. You'll need a valid [access_token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) for the user and this user *must* have "installed" your application before you can send them notifications like this OR use the [Requests Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/). Afterwards, it's as simple as sending a POST to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{USER_ID}/apprequests?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

or

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/apprequests?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

The only required parameter to be sent is "message", but you can also send a JSON-encoded dictionary of parameters in the "data" parameter. I recommend you play with the [API Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?). There you can send yourself apprequests with a POST, check your pending ones with a GET and clear pending requests with a DELETE request to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{ID_OF_REQUEST_OBJECT}
```

If you're developing an application *on* Facebook (like a canvas app), you can make use of the [Requests Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) which makes sending the POST very easy and gives you a friend selector as well.

You can also get the user's pending apprequests by sending a GET request to the same object.