# Inviting Facebook friends through iPhone App

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-friends, facebook-invite

I've been searching this question, and I haven't been able to find anything that works.  I have an iPhone app that allows users to link their Facebook account.   It would look something like this:

Once a user has successfully linked to FB, I want to present them with a list of their FB friends and an option to invite selected friends.

FB Friend 1...........        Invite  
FB Friend 2...........        Invite  
... 
FB Friend 1000.....        Invite

Basically, I want to send a message to FB friends that says something like "Check out this app".  I'm pretty sure this has to go to either their notifications or wall and cannot go as a FB message, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Also, I don't need to select a group of friends to invite -- this can be done one at a time.  So it would look like this:

FB Friend 1...........        *invited*  
FB Friend 2...........        Invite  
... 
FB Friend 1000.....        Invite

Thanks so much for any help you can provide.

Comment: Hey, have you found the solution of this problem? I also have the same  requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there isn't anything in the iOS SDK that presents the apprequests dialog, and a user has to have installed/approved your application before you can send them application notifications via a POST request...

> Requests are a great way to enable users to invite their friends,
>   accept a gift or help them complete a mission in your app. There are
>   now two types of requests that can be sent from an app:
>
> **User-generated requests**: These requests are confirmed by a user’s
>   explicit action on a request dialog. These requests update the
>   bookmark count for the recipient. You send requests by using the
>   recently launched Request Dialog.
>
> **App-generated requests**: **These
>   requests can be initiated and sent only to users who have authorized
>   your app.** Developers can send these requests using the Graph API. Use
>   these requests to update the bookmark count to encourage a user to
>   re-engage in the app (e.g., your friend finished her move in a game
>   and it’s now your turn).

The only way to get this is via Facebook's Requests 2.0 dialog (which is not currently available to the Facebook iOS SDK):

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/453

See more here in this related question...

[Sending application requests that appear in the left column on Facebook home page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469464/sending-application-requests-that-appear-in-the-left-column-on-facebook-home-page)

Comment: Thanks for the info, and that's too bad to hear it can't be done throught the iOS SDK.   I'm wondering: can have the app pass the request (message, ID, etc) to my server and then use the Requests 2.0 dialog mentioned above?

Comment: ^ I guess this might require sharing an access token which I'm not sure can be done

Comment: Yeah, you could probably open a browser window (or load into a UIWebView) to your html app and load in the request there.